# Como colocar ponto e vígula automaticamente em java script?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

// 1 - Number
console.log(2)

// queira que quando eu desse enter o vs code adicionasse um ponto e vígula automaticamente
// ficando assim

// 1 - Number
console.log(2);

Comment: Na barra de menus eme "Command Palette", procure por Preferências: Abrir Configurações (JSON), para poder editar o settings.json: `{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "javascript.format.insertSemicolons": true
}`

Answer (score -1):

baixei a extensao do prettier. Depois segui as configurações: abrir configurações do vscode `ctrl + ,` -> Extensões -> prettier -> marcar a opção Prettier:Semi